# Cannot find variable

Tags: java, variables, jakarta-ee

I'm creating a simple system that can add, search, update and delete data. My work is almost complete, except with the update part. I tried any possible fixes to the problem, which is a variable I used.

Here is the code that I used:

```
try{
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   Connection con= (Connection)       
   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tvatpms","root","");
   Statement stmte=con.createStatement();

    String acn  =  jTextField3.getText();
    String c_name  =  jTextField10.getText();
    String c_address=jTextField4.getText();
    String c_tin=jTextField5.getText();
    String c_bln=jTextField6.getText();
    String c_ea=jTextField7.getText();
    String c_tn=jTextField8.getText();
    String c_fn=jTextField9.getText();
    String c_cp=jTextField2.getText();



String sql=("UPDATE client SET c_name='" + (c_name) "', c_address='" + (c_address)+ "',      c_tin='" + (c_tin)+ "',  c_bln='" + (c_bln)+ "', c_ea='" + (c_ea)+ "', c_tn='" + (c_tn)+ "', c_fn='" + (c_fn)+ "', c_cp='" + (c_cp)+"' where acn = '" + (acn) + "'");


stmte.executeUpdate(sql);


    jTextField10.setText("");
    jTextField4.setText("");
    jTextField5.setText("");
    jTextField6.setText("");
    jTextField7.setText("");
    jTextField8.setText("");
    jTextField9.setText("");
    jTextField2.setText("");


JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"DATABASE UPDATED");

}
     catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Database not updated!","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        //  Logger.getLogger(log.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);     
     }
```

The problem is the string sql part. It says that the program can't find the c_name variable, which was declared above. Can someone help me? I'm still new in using Java so help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Show us the exact error message. The one in your title and the one in your question body are different.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Are you missing a `+` sign after `(c_name)` ?

Comment: Your are missing the plus after (c_name).

Comment: You are missing "+" after (c_name)

Comment: Oh my. Yes! There's a missing +! Thank you so much.

Comment: When there's a user called "root" with a password of empty string, the least of the OP's problems is the SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 2):

I think PreparedStatement would be one perfect solution to avoid this type of problem
Try this

```
String sql="UPDATE client SET c_name=?,c_address=?,c_tin=?,c_bln=?,c_ea=?,c_tn=?," +
        " c_fn=?,c_cp=? where acn = ?";
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setString(1, c_name);
statement.setString(2,c_address);
statement.setString(3,c_tin);
statement.setString(4,c_bln);
statement.setString(5,c_ea);
statement.setString(6,c_tn);
statement.setString(7,c_fn);
statement.setString(8,c_cp);
statement.setString(9,acn);
statement.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `+` operator after `(c_name)`:

```
    String sql=("UPDATE client SET c_name='" + (c_name) + // This + was missing
                "', c_address='" + (c_address) + 
                "',      c_tin='" + (c_tin) + 
                "',  c_bln='" + (c_bln) +
                "', c_ea='" + (c_ea) +
                "', c_tn='" + (c_tn) +
                "', c_fn='" + (c_fn) +
                "', c_cp='" + (c_cp) +
                "' where acn = '" + (acn) + "'");
```

Note:
There are quit a bit of whitespaces in the update statement in the OP. I've left them untouched, but note that they don't serve any useful purpose.